# Copy all data from the GLOBathy dataset by country to a new folder

Tags: r, gis, qgis

The GLOBathy is a dataset with bathymetry for almost every lake on the planet (15.58GB .zip available at this [link](https://springernature.figshare.com/articles/dataset/GLOBathy_Bathymetry_Rasters/13404635)). It contains 1.4m+ records split into a number of sub-directories. There are associated attribute tables which record the country each file belongs to ([link](https://springernature.figshare.com/articles/dataset/GLOBathy_Waterbodies_Maximum_Depth_and_Geophysical_Parameters/13402070)).

Extracting data from the sub-directories is somewhat cumbersome as there is no 'intuitive' sequence to the file names relative to which country they belong to. Further, I have found GIS programs to be extremely slow at extracting data from multiple directories and the most often require a loop at some level.

I am self-answering this question to: a) provide a solution for others that may have this issue; and b) see if anyone knows a more efficient method.

Comment: Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: @Chris Done. Let me know if you find any issues. I only test this on New Zealand (n=517) and it was fairly quick. Not sure how long it would take for Canada (n = 879987) but I can't foresee any issues other than time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method to extract files from the GLOBathy data by country. I have annotated the code, comment if clarification is required or if issues are found:

```
library(dplyr)

# Load the GLOBathy_basic_parameters(ALL_LAKES).csv file
GLOBathy_all <- read.csv("C:/GLOBathy_basic_parameters/GLOBathy_basic_parameters(ALL_LAKES).csv",
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Define country of interest
country_sub <- "New Zealand"

# Define output directory (must already exist)
output_folder <- "C:/New Zealand"

# Extract records from GLOBathy_all that match country_sub and create associated file paths
GLOBathy_sub <- GLOBathy_all %>%
  filter(Country == country_sub) %>% # Filter by country
  mutate(temp1 = ifelse(Hylak_id > 1400000, # Get upper value of sub folder
                        nrow(GLOBathy_all),
                        paste0(ceiling(Hylak_id / 100000) * 100, "K")),
         temp2 = ifelse(Hylak_id <= 100000, # Round Hylak_id down to nearest 100000, two steps required for cases where Hylak_id == upper threshhold of folder names
                        1,
                        floor(Hylak_id / 100000) * 100000),
         temp3 = ifelse(temp2 == 1, # Get lower value of sub folder
                        paste0(1,  "_"),
                        ifelse(temp2 > 100000 & temp2 == Hylak_id, # If value == folder threshhold, subtract 100000
                               paste0((temp2 - 100000) / 1000, "K_"),
                               paste0(temp2 / 1000, "K_"))),
         temp4 = ceiling(Hylak_id / 1000) * 1000, # Get upper value of sub sub folder
         temp5 = paste0(temp4 - 999, "_"), # Get lower value of sub sub folder
         folders = paste0("C:/Bathymetry_Rasters/", # Create folder path
                          temp3, temp1, "/", temp5, temp4),
         files = paste0(folders, "/", Hylak_id, "_bathymetry.tif")) %>% # Create file path
  select(-contains("temp"))

# Copy files to new directory
file.copy(GLOBathy_sub$files, output_folder)
```

Comment: [NATURE: GLOBathy, the global lakes bathymetry dataset 2022, Open Access](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41597-022-01132-9). I need to explore this trove in the context of only unzipping parts of as my HD is nearing the end of its useful data volume life. Your above provides ways to think about navigating as metadata in the article is somewhat uninformative. And welcome to 1300+

Comment: @Chris Haha thanks. Totally understand about the storage issue, I'm currently extracting data for Canada and my poor 500GB SSD is quite full already. And yes, the metadata is decidedly average. However, GLOBathy_basic_parameters(ALL_LAKES).csv has lat/longs for the lake pour points so you may be able to integrate the `sf` package to further reduce the search area and to exclude lakes of a certain size.

Comment: And your interest in hydrology? given your research in social (power) epidemiology, Foucault lurks. Though I confess I love hydrology in a way that makes practicing hydrologists cringe as I see the 1-D flow charts as analogous to early eye-tracking plots.

Comment: Wanting to create some hillshades (lakeshades?) to represent lakes in the base layer of a cultural map I'm doing for fun. I intend to standardise symbology for all lake features regardless of relative elevation e.g. all lakes have a surface elevation of 0m. Did try to create my own using etopo data and lake polygon files but I was capturing elevation outside the lake polygons which made my method impractical. Using the GLOBathy ended up being more time-efficient and robust

Comment: FYI using the SSD of my Win10 machine, copying the Canada lake files (n = 879987, 7.71GB) took 2.216754 hours

Comment: I received a warning when HD dipped below 1GB and aborted.

Comment: @Chris bummer, but also good to know an error gets thrown instead of potentially erroneous results being produced.

Comment: It wasn't integrated process as you're imagining, while download was happening, at about 14GB, kernel threw up a warning about 1GB (or less) left, and I scrambled and aborted download, like pulling the match back from the gasoline. Just happened to be sitting there, twiddling my thumbs...